# Trinomial equation - combinatorial explanation

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-proofs, multinomial-coefficients

Assume that $e+f+g=n$.

Prove:

$P(n;e,f,g)=P(n-1;e-1,f,g) + P(n-1;e,f-1,g) + P(n-1;e,f,g-1)$

Where $P(n;e,f,g)$ is the tri-nomial-coefficient of n over e,f,g ($\frac{n!}{e!f!g!}$)

Combinatorially.

Comment: What does $P$ represent here?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Imagine you have a line with $n$ blanks and an alphabet consisting of $\{E,F,G\}.$ Call $P(n;e,f,g)$ the number of ways that you create a word with exactly $e$ E's, $f$ F's and $g$ G's. 
For the RHS assume that you are going to fix the last letter. You have $3$ options and in each option you will end with $n-1$ blanks.
For the LHS imagine first that every letter is different, in how many ways can you create a permutation of those $n$ letters? Now, you now that they are not different, you know that there are $e$ E's and so in how many ways can you just order those? Use multiplication principle.